# How does the save system of the Konami Castlevania Anniversary Collection work?

Tags: castlevania-series

How does the save system work exactly in the **Konami Castlevania Anniversary Collection**? Since this collection contains games that didn't have a save system back in the day it's not really clear how the game can be saved.

Does it work in save-state kind of way that you can save at any point and reload from that point onwards any time during a stage? Or does it auto-save after completing a stage and let's you restart from that point onwards? Or something completely different?

Comment: I'm currently researching this myself, as it's the one thing that doesn't seem to work on Proton. It seems to be some kind of a emulator state save; but I'm not yet certain where it's stored. There is a guide on extracting the ROMs from the local folder, but I haven't tried it yet: https://steamcommunity.com/app/1018010/discussions/0/1628539187767686145/